# Erro 'Método não-estático requer um destino.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

Eu estou com um probleminha e preciso da ajuda de vocês para me ajudar a resolver.
[image: .]

Como o erro esta ocorrendo:

Basicamente ele esta ocorrendo, quando clico em um botão para ele abrir um modal para trazendo as informações que eu quero dentro desta listagem, porem essa "Ocorrencias", é necessária para outras modais (Telas front), eu estou usando ele para aproveitar e pegar o `idCarregamento`,  para eu fazer a comparação e trazer as informações.

Sei que ali ta `firstordefault();` porem creio q seja desse jeito pois estou querendo 1 informação

Comment: Esse erro geralmente ocorre por que há alguma variável com referência nula em uma expressão lambda, confere a model (OcorrenciaDataModel model), ela está null??

Comment: Campeão verifica se o model ou model.idOcorrencia esta null.
Tive um erro assim e a resposta do amigo Adimar resolveu pra mim, era algo dentro da expressão que estava nulo.

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente esse erro ocorre quando algum objeto da sua expressão está nulo.

Faz uma verificação antes pra saber se esse ctx.tb_ocorrencia é nulo, só depois de ter certeza vc de fato faz seu select.